# Having problem with import in ES6 module: property is not exported

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, es6-modules

I'm currently working with redux, and I'm exporting an object with the type properties to my reducer file.

My types.js file:

```
const Types = {LOG_IN:'LOG_IN',REGISTER:'REGISTER'};
export default Types;
```

My reducer.js file:

```
import {LOG_IN,REGISTER} from './types';
//CODE HERE
```

When I compile, however, CRA give me an error:

```
Attempted import error: 'LOG_IN' is not exported from './types'.
```

Curiously enough, this code works:

```
import Types from './types';
const {LOG_IN,REGISTER} = Types;
```

Why is it that my code structure doesn't work with that form of importing while React's and Redux's code does? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly define a named export for each constant for that to work.

```
export const LOG_IN = 'LOG_IN';
export const REGISTER = 'REGISTER';
```

Importing a named export is not the same thing as destructuring a default export, which is what's happening when you do this:

```
import Types from './types';
const {LOG_IN,REGISTER} = Types;
```

You can [read more on this here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export). Other code you find in the wild might appear to work like you describe because it's actually defining its exports like this:

```
module.exports = {
  LOG_IN: 'LOG_IN'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think is because you export **Types**, if tou can use **LOG_IN** for example you need to access **Types.LOG_IN**, and the code **const {LOG_IN,REGISTER} = Types;** works because you are using destructuring

the

```
import Types from './types';
```

are correct

an then try to access with `Types.REGISTER`